# Distinct values from a field in vespa

Tags: vespa

I'm using vespa to view some data. Consider the following data

`id    product    brand
 1     a          b1
 2     b          b1
 3     c          b1
 4     d          b2
 5     e          b3`

I tried grouping to display the data from brand field. I had a field with price and I wrote a query like this 
`SELECT * FROM s_data where default contains "soap" | all(group(brand) each(output(sum(price))));`
Basically, I don't want to calculate the sum of price, all I want is distinct values from the field 'brand'. Is there a way to do that in vespa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`all(group(brand) each(output(count())))`

Gives you all the unique values of the brand field attribute along with their occurrences count. If you really don't need the count you can ignore it in the output.